# Oracle SQL Flight Database - Find flight from A to B with stopover?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a flight Database with the following table:

```
FID    from fto dep   arrive  days  flightno
----  ----- --- ----  ------  ----  --------
 167    MPB KYM 1020    1040     0  EA5203    
 168    MPB KYM 1510    1530     0  EA5205    
 169    MPB KYM 1705    1725     0  EA5207    
 221    NEB KYM  850    1025     0  EA782     
 222    NEB KYM 1355    1530     0  EA784     
 223    NEB KYM 1810    1945     0  EA786     
 557    BAH NEB 1305    1500     0  EA686     
 558    BAH ELM  605     715     0  EA162     
 559    BAH ELM 1005    1115     0  EA340     
 560    BAH ELM 1230    1340     0  EA872     
 561    BAH ELM 1325    1435     0  EA442     
 562    BAH ELM 1400    1510     0  EA872     
 563    BAH ELM 1455    1605     0  EA978     
 564    BAH ELM 1640    1750     0  EA640     
 565    BAH ELM 2025    2135     0  EA940     
 566    BAH YDS  645     845     0  EA992     
 567    BAH YDS  945    1130     0  EA974     
1163    PPP KYM 1040    1110     0  EA3201    
1164    PPP KYM 1450    1520     0  EA3207    
1190    OKR KYM  825     920     0  EA3200    
1191    OKR KYM 1010    1100     0  EA3204    
1192    OKR KYM 1500    1605     0  EA3214    
1517    SVT KYM  810     920     0  EA3201    
1518    SVT KYM  940    1050     0  EA3201    
1519    SVT KYM 1215    1310     0  EA3211    
1520    SVT KYM 1510    1605     0  EA3211
```

How do I query it to show indirect flights from BAH to KYM?
I've tried a number of ways to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how we can understand indirect flight?

Comment: For example BAH to NEB and then NEB to KYM. One "stopover"

Comment: can you add text example data? So, we can test our question.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean? Like that?

Comment: You have three NEB to KYM,  How do you know which one?

Comment: I need the query to identify all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select CONNECT_BY_ROOT ffrom ||SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(fto, '/') path_ ,level,ffrom,fto
from FLIGHTS_TABLE
where level > 1
start with ffrom='BAH' CONNECT BY PRIOR fto =ffrom ORDER SIBLINGS By ffrom ;
```

It retuns :

```
PATH_       |LEVEL| FFROM | FTO
BAH/NEB/KYM | 2   | NEB   | KYM
BAH/NEB/KYM | 2   | NEB   | KYM
BAH/NEB/KYM | 2   | NEB   | KYM
```

It returns 3 rows because of there are 3 row/flight from 'NEB' to 'KYM'. I don't know which flight is indirect flight.